# NGINX redirect to URL if the requested server returns status code

Tags: nginx

I have a basic nginx server set up and now I want to make specific different servers.
I have one central server which hosts a website, and two java applications which both serve APIs.
Unfortunately, it is hard for me to redirect the users to a specific URL if they do something wrong in the java application.
I want it so that when the Status Code that the proxied Server (the server I got proxied to by nginx) returned is a specific one, it redirects you to a specific URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using a NGINX built in feature: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page